# ¿Cómo quitar filas de un datagridview que tienen como datasource una bindingList?

Tags: c#, datagrid

como dice la pregunta, tengo 2 datagrids que se llenan con binding lists, las cuales lleno con datos de la bd utilizando EF, tengo 2 tablas, una de Documentos y otra de Imágenes, un documento puede tener muchas imagenes y muchas imágenes pertenecen a un Documento. El asunto es que en el datagrid, coloqué un botón de eliminar, con el que elimino esos datos de mi datagrid. Para el caso de documentos, lo quita también del datagrid lo hago de esta mantera:

```
bDocumentos.Remove(bDocumentos[indexDocumento]);
```

al ejectutar eso, se quita del datagridview. Tengo lo mismo para el de imágenes:

```
bArchivo.Remove(bArchivo[indexArchivo]);
```

dónde en ambos, indexDocumento e indexArchivo, son el index de los datagridviews. Como ya dije, en el caso del datagridview de Documentos, también se quita del dgv (datagridview) pero en el caso de el de imágenes no hace nada.

Alguna idea de cómo puedo cambiar esto? La manera en que lleno los grids es así:

```
dgvDocumentos.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        DocPOCO = expediente.Documentos.ToList();
        bDocumentos = new BindingList<DocumentoPOCO>(DocPOCO);
        foreach(var doc in expediente.Documentos)
        {
            foreach(var img in doc.Archivos)
            {
                archivoPOCO.Add(img);
            }
        }
        bArchivo = new BindingList<ArchivoPOCO>(archivoPOCO);
        dgvImagenes.DataSource = false;
        dgvDocumentos.DataSource = bDocumentos;
```

donde DocPOCO es una list normal de Documentos y lo mismo para archivoPOCO pero para imágenes. en el caso del datagrid de archivo, se llena al dar clic a un archivo, así:

```
private void dgvDocumentos_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dgvImagenes.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvImagenes.DataSource = bArchivo.Where(x=> x.idDocumento == bDocumentos[indexDocumento].idDocumento).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buenas Alex,

El problema que se te presenta es que, como muestras en tu código, estás llenando la `dgvDocumentos` con un `BindingList`, pero la `dgvImagenes` la llenas con una `List<>` haciendo lo siguiente:

```
dgvImagenes.DataSource = bArchivo.Where(x=> x.idDocumento == bDocumentos[indexDocumento].idDocumento).ToList();
```

Para que te funcione como los documentos deberías llenar el `DataSource` de `dgvImagenes` de la siguiente manera:

```
dgvImagenes.DataSource = new BindingList<ArchivoPOCO>(bArchivo.Where(x=> x.idDocumento == bDocumentos[indexDocumento].idDocumento).ToList());
```

De ésta forma conviertes la `List<>` a `BindingList`, como haces con los Documentos.

Comment: No se me había ocurrido jaja, muchas gracias!